# Unable to install gnome-tweaks, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, 20.04, gnome-tweaks

When I type on the terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

I get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-tweaks : Depends: gnome-shell-extension-prefs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Doing the same for `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` shows a more detailed error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1~wip1 is to be installed
                               Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) but 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1~wip1 is to be installed
                               Recommends: chrome-gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However I have no held packages, `apt-mark showhold` has empty output. For some reason `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` depends on WIP dependencies, and something is preventing me from installing them. Do I have to allow dependencies from unstable channels or something like that? What could be the issue here?

Comment: Thanks for the multiple links, I'll look into it.